# IFS not working when cell is blank in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in the Google Sheet

[image]

The column B will have the value from **Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4**

I want to calculate the number of data with each Quarter value, so I used the following formula in a cell

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(Initiatives!B13:B, "Q2", Initiatives!A13:A))
```

[image]

But it shows blank when there is no count

In another cell, I have to print 5 when the count is 0, so I put

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(Calculator!E10), 5)
```

But it prints nothing, whereas the `ISBLANK()` check gives True

**How can I print 5 when the cell is blank or 0.**

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12VCFZTLjdxcY8SoP-jkoIB7lZiE66RmnuAFWzXHgdVg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you have an error in the formulas `H5:K5` - `COUNTIF` function must have two arguments, perhaps:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(B3:B, "Q1"))
```

second - cells `H15:K15` background color is the same as the font color - you will not see any results,

third - the function `IFS` under the condition `ISBLANK (H5)` will return zero, change to 1 if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to test if blank? Just try in H5

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$B, H3 )
```

and copy / paste to the right for Q2, Q3, Q4.

In H15

```
=MIN(5,H5+1)
```